# how to "manage" the ms sql server express database which comes with visual studio (community)?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Ok, So I just installed visual studio code with 150GB of libraries and tools, and the episerver plugin.  When you fire up a new episerver project, it magically creates a database.

I need to wipe this database some how, or create a new one and point episerver to this.

The question is, how?

If this was mysql, I would fire up heidisql, or mysql workbench, put in localhost:3306 and the admin username and password.

I tried installing SSMS, but when I run this, it does not see any databases - it doesn't seem to be able to "see" sql server express databases.

Trying to reverse engineer this, episerver is using the following connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EPiServerDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|EPiServerDB_faa2d554.mdf;Initial Catalog=EPiServerDB_faa2d554;Connection Timeout=60;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Googling revealed one lead: sqlcmd.

But I have no idea what parameters I need to connect?  I dont know what the server, port, username, password or database name is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried telling SSMS to connect to `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I did this, but I think you'd have your connect window like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

And then when conencted you'd right click the databases node and choose Attach... (and pick the `EPiServerDB_faa2d554.mdf`

You might be able to specify the filename in the Additional Connection Parameters in the advanced

Comment: Thanks.  How did you get this connection dialog?

Comment: It appears when you launch SSMS (sql server management studio), but you can also call it up by pressing the connect button in the object explorer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SQLCMD /S (LocalDb) /d EPiServerDB_faa2d554
```

This should connect you to the database.

Otherwise, if you want to connect through SSMS, you can try:

```
Server Name: (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB
```

or just

```
Server Name: (LocalDb)
```